# Is there a possibility to recover rewritten backup copy of an iPhone from iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, ios

Is there a possibility to recover rewritten backup copy of an iPhone from iTunes?

The thing is, I accidentally rewrote the former backup with current and now need to get the previous one.

Please help, this is really important.

Comment: You can't, the old backup doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

1. If you do an iOS upgrade via iTunes and haven't backed up the phone locally "in a while", iTunes will do a backup and include the date and time in the name, so it won't overwrite an existing backup. You can see these backups in Preferences… > Devices. I don't know when iTunes decides to do an automatic backup, but that's a place to look.
2. The backups are stored in ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup on a Mac and \Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\ on Windows 7, so if you back up that directory, you may have the desired backup on your backup device/service.

If you don't have the desired backup in either of those places then it's no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

If you have backed up your iPhone through iTunes your old backup will still be there. Open iTunes goto preferences then select devices and you will see all the backups you had done. Select the appropriate one and restore. Hope, this helps you